# Saleforce and Pega Integration

Tags: rest-api, case

How can I create a service case in Salesforce from Pegasystems external application without using connected app?

Answer (score 0):

You can't avoid making a Connected App in Salesforce (and shouldn't want to avoid making one).

Connected Apps are the mechanism that provides some semblance of security, and this is *definitely not* the type of thing that you want to make available to the internet at large.